# Moving TextField on touch

Tags: input, libgdx, scene2d

So I want to be able to move a textfield when I touch it. At the moment this code makes it move as soon as I touch the screen. I want it only to move as I touch IT. 
123123123123123123123123123

```
InputListener drag = new InputListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer) {
            textField.setOrigin(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
            textField.setPosition(x, y);
            super.touchDragged(event, x, y, pointer);
        }





    };

    textField.addListener(drag);


    game.inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();


    game.inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    game.inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stagePurc);
    game.inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stageText);





    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(game.inputMultiplexer);
```

Here I set the textField to it´s stage:

```
stageText.addActor(textField);
    stageText.addActor(textArea);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create new `InputProcessor` for your `TextField`. It is already can listen for clicks.

After you set stage as an `InputProcessor` with `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage)` (or with `inputMultiplexer` if you wish) and added your `TextField` to the stage you can add `InputListener` to your `TextField`:

```
    ...

    TextField textField = new TextField("test", textFieldStyle);
    someTable.add(textField);

    InputListener mouseListener = new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            // Here you can do the movement of the textField
            // ...
            System.out.println("click"); 
            return true;
        }
    };
    textField.addListener(mouseListener);

    ...
```

Code in this `touchDown()` method will trigger only when `textField` is clicked.

Comment: If I change my InputProcessor to InputListener I can´t add it to the inputMultiplexer? Therefor the touchDown won´t work.

Comment: You don't need to add `TextField` to `inputMultiplexer` directly. You have to add `TextField` to `stage` and add `stage` to `inputMultiplexor`. That's all. `Stage` will send clicks to all listeners within itself automatically.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Look at my first post, I´ve changed it to how I´ve done thing now considering what you said. And with that code the textField doesn´t move when touched.

Comment: Did you add `textField` to your `stage`? This is not reflected in your code sample. And how do you move `textField`? I don't see any move methods.

Comment: 1) In your question you wanted your `textField` to respond to click but you added `setPosition()` to `touchDragged()` method. Why? Do you drag this `textField` or click it? 2) Method `setOrigin()` looks really strange here and doesn't make any sense. Read the documentation carefully about it. 3) Set breakpoint or/and `println()` for debug to `touchDown()`, `touchUp()` and `touchDragged()` to see how they work.